# Fedora 22 Live Install to Docking Station

Tags: fedora

More a Fedora Live question than a Linux question, but the responses to my queries on this forum have been reliable.

In Fedora 22, my boot hard disk is assigned device sda, while my external (hard disk) docking station is assigned device sdc.  I have installed Fedora 22 live to a flash drive.  Suppose I boot up with the flash drive and choose the option to install the operating system (rather than merely previewing Fedora 22).

Will it allow me to install directly to the docking station hard disk (device sdc), thus leaving my boot disk (device sda) totally untouched?

Comment: Fedora is a Linux distribution and therefore on topic here -- no need for the disclaimer. (Although, disclaimer of my own: I work on Fedora.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can select which drives to use in the installer, in the **Installation Destination** section. This will present pictures of each drive detected on your system, and you can select which ones you want. Instructions for this step of the F22 installer can be found at https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-gui-storage-partitioning.html

PS: the current release is F23; I'd recommend installing that instead of F22 unless you have a compelling reason.